# Extend property from another css file

Tags: css, sass

How do I extend a property from an another css file?

```
@import "bootstrap.min.css";

.stat-bar
{
   @extend .progress;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you can only import sass files, unless you use sass-css-importer ([see this](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/556)). This means that you can only extend properties from other sass files, see this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118845/how-to-extend-from-another-sass-file-or-how-to-achieve-oosass) for more information about how to do it.

Comment: Well that sucks. Just another slight question, do you know if `less` supports this sort of use case?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, sorry.